# Passwordless ssh not working?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I set up passwordless ssh between my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop laptop and my server running Ubuntu Server 14.04. It was all working. Then, I rebooted my server, and after that it stopped working. I tried generating new keys and copying them again, checking the sshd_config serveral times, and fixing permissions for the .ssh folder, but nothing is working. I set the sshd_config log level to DEBUG, and this line appears whenever I try to connect:

```
Sep  8 20:06:16 hostname sshd[19724]: debug1: trying public key file /home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys
Sep  8 20:06:16 hostname sshd[19724]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

Obviously it does not access the authorized keys file to check my key. I tried deleting the .ssh folder so it would recreate it, and it did, but still failed to find the file. I tried fixing the permissions many times, and nothing is working.

Comment: Do you have an encrypted home directory?

Comment: On the  remote host or my laptop?

Comment: Presumably on the server, but wherever `/home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys` is located.